# For loop in Julia. Syntax confusion

Tags: for-loop, syntax, julia

I am a complete noob in Julia and its syntax. I am trying to follow [this](https://shuvomoy.github.io/blog/programming/2020/03/16/Solving-SDPs-in-Julia.html) article on semi-definite-programming on Julia.

I would apprecieate if someone can help me figure out what the for loop in `In[4]` actually does:

```
for i in 1:m
A[:, (i-1)*n+1:i*n] .= random_mat_create(n)
b[i] = tr(A[:, (i-1)*n+1:i*n]*X_test)
end
```

To my understanding it should create a vector of matrices `A` (m of those) as well as an m-dimensional vector `b`.  I am totally confused though on the indexing of `A` and the indexing of `b`.

**I would like an explanation of the** `:, (i-1)*n+1:i*n` **part of this code**. The reason I ask here is because I also dont know what to Google or what to search for in Julia documentation.

Comment: The : in array access by itself means the whole axis. The part after the comma is the next axis, and it's building a range along that axis.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb comment, you mean the matrix column?

Comment: Column is just one of the axes in a matrix (array with 2 dimensions), you can specify access along multiple axes in Julia by separating them with commas. If you're familiar with numpy it's the same deal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, this looks like numpy or panda, but I do not understand the input after the column I guess. The purpose of this loop is to fill this vector of matrices but the indexing still is cryptic to me.

Comment: Advanced indexing takes a bit to get used to, you'll get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(i-1)*n+1:i*n` creates a range from `(i-1)*n + 1` to `i*n`. For example, if `i`=2 and `n`=10, this range becomes `11:20`, so `A[:, (i-1)*n+1:i*n]` will grab all the rows of `A` (that's what `:` does), and columns 11-20.

Comment: I see. This is it then, the second `:` creates the range then. Its a bit confusing because when writting something like `a=rand([0:9], 2, 2)` I do not get a 2x2 matrix with random values between 0 and 9 rather random placements of "0:9" within this 2x2 matrix.

Comment: That is because `[0:9]` is different from `0:9`. You should use `rand(0:9, 2, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two operations there that are not clear to you:

- `:` operator. Consider a `Matrix` `a = zeros(3,3)`. You could use array slicing operator (similarly to numpy or Matlab) to select the entire second columns as: `a[1:end,2]`. However, when selecting everything from start to the `end` those two values can be omitted and hence you can write `a[:,2]` (this always looked the easiest way for me to remember that)
- `.` (dot) operator. Julia is very careful about what gets vectorized and what not. In numpy or R, vectorizing operations happens kind of always automatically. In Julia you have the control - but with the control comes the responsibility. Hence trying to assign values to the second column by writing `a[:, 2] = 5.0` will throw an error because there is vector on the right and a scalar on the left. If you want to vectorize you need to tell that to Julia. Hence the dot operator `.=` means "perform element-wise assignment". Note that any Julia function or operator, even your own functions can be decorated by such dot `.`. Since this is a very important language feature have a look at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Although I do understand the slicing operator `:` in the context of arrays what confuses me here is that there is a second `:` operator.

Comment: what do you mean by "second"? In your code `:` is always about array slicing. BTW try typying `?:` in the Julia console

Comment: I refer to the "range" that vin93843 mentioned above.

Comment: `1:10` is Pythons equivalent of `range(1,11)` - that's all. In Julia this could also be written as `(:)(1,10)` or `UnitRange(1,10)`. Simply writing a colon is shorter.